# distinct in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

i want to select from a mysql table

title , url from the table

title can be duplicate so  i need distinct title from them'

if i use sachin's code then i find duplicate rows so how i can get the information where title not show again as the result. means no duplicate title get from table in mysql

Comment: can you add your specific data here? Else you can always use select distinct * from <tablename>

Comment: Use the DISTINCT clause in your query 
eg: Select DISTINCT columnname from TableName.
If your scenario is not this stright forward, then please post more details

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  DISTINCT *
FROM    mytable
```

**Update:**

```
SELECT  b.title, b.url
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT title
        FROM    blah
        WHERE   cID = 1856
        ) bd
JOIN    blah b
ON      b.id = 
        (
        SELECT  bi.id
        FROM    blah bi
        WHERE   bi.cID = 1856
                AND bi.title = bd.title
        ORDER BY
                cid, title, url, id
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `(cid, title, url, id)` for this to work fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct a.title, a_url FROM blah WHERE a.cID = 1856
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` applies to the whole record, so you query may return duplicates on `title`. You may omit the parenthesis, they are only confusing.

Answer (score 0):

here is the sollution

SELECT * FROM  blah WHERE info.cID = 1856 GROUP BY title

Comment: This will work, though it does not guarantee which `url` will be returned for each `title`.

Comment: Correct me If I am wrong, I think this wont work unless you have your "a_url" column in the group by clause too which will again get you duplicate entries

Comment: @Quassnoi: Thank you very much. This was a new information to learn for me. Very helpful indeed.